# Get month-wise data from a table which has total year records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in that in one column I have a list of userid's separated by commas, and another column with date, this action is repeated for every day. How can I get month-wise data of who attends the class based on user id.

[image]

I need data like month-wise.

[image]

Comment: You've tagged this with MySQL. MySQL is a relational database management system, but this schema has nothing to do with relational data, so one way or the other you may wish to consider ways to address that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate userId else that will make very complicated sql and slow your server down. One record for date to userid. Then it is very simple;

```
select count(id) from `table` GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date)
```